# In which folder should I place REST resources in a dynamic web app?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am building a Dynamic Web Application and was wondering in which folder to place the RESTful resources that I am going to expose to others.

There are three folders:

src/main/java

src/main/resources

src/test/java

I already put my business logic and data access layers in the src/main/java folder. Should the RESTful resources go in src/main/resources, or be in part of the src/main/java folder as well?

Auto complete does not work in files in the resources folder, so Eclipse is not showing any errors, as it is not set in the Java Build Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your RESTful resources are annotated classes they should be placed together with another java sources: `src/main/java`

Answer (score 1):

Your REST class is normal java class so it should go to the src/main/java.

But then it must be exposed as REST service. If you are not using full Java EE container annotation of the class with @Path will not be enough.

So you need to include RS implementation for example Jersey.
Then, add the listener/servlet to your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And map it to a path:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/YOUR_PATH/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```